# Как установить Laravel Homestead PHP5 / PHP56?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

[Установил Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead) а там PHP v7.

Не хочется лезть в убунту и в ручную менять версию.

У меня Vagrant + Virtualbox.

Как установить [тоже самое](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead) но с другой версией php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите работать с версией фреймворка 5.5, то нет смысла менять версию т.к. она поддерживает только версию PHP 7.0+.
Если до 5.5 - то проблема для вас заключается в том что нужен Homestead версии 2+.

Его можно установить следующим образом:

```
git clone https://github.com/gjrdiesel/homestead.git ~/Homestead56
cd ~/Homestead56; bash init.sh; vagrant up
```

Это не официальный репозиторий, а его форк, если вам нужно перенести сайты с уже созданного Homestead, то нужно сделать следующее:

```
git clone https://github.com/gjrdiesel/homestead.git ~/Homestead56
cd ~/Homestead56; cp -rv ~/.homestead/ ~/.homestead-56/; vagrant up
```

Но лучше советую перейти на PHP7, версия Homestead с PHP5 уже года 2-3 не обновлялась и не понятно как она сейчас будет работать.

Ну или как альтернативный вариант лезть в саму машину, так что в любом случае придется посидеть, легко это не сделать.